# How can a function use variables generated by other (functions) as parameters for itself in python?

Tags: python, function, modular

I'm learning python and I would like to separate the different processes of my code into different functions. To do that I need to give variables of previous function as a parameter to an other function . I tried some thing like this

```
def F1 (A):
   B=A+1 

def F2 (B):
   C=B+1
   print C
```

F1(1)
F2()

For example in this case I expect to get 3 as a final result.

But It doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work -- what were you expecting?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#id479555 (do read the entire article). I have a feeling what "doesn't work" is that Python _is_ separating your code.. into function namespaces. But you didn't give a clue what you were expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `return` it:

```
def F1 (A):
   return A+1

def F2 (B):
   C=B+1
   print C

# Then use it as parameter
F2(F1(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Since you've edited your post: variables created within functions are local to that function, meaning you can't reference them elsewhere unless you use the `global` command, e.g. `global myvar`. This isn't recommended though, it would be better if your code looked like this:

```
def F1 (A):
  return A+1

def F2 (B):
 return B+1

first = F1(1)
second = F2(first)

print first, second
```

Remember, `def F2 (B):` means 'use `B` as a parameter' -- parameters are undefined until you call the function with a value.

--- original answer ---

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but let me try and explain functions:

```
def F1(A):
  ...
```

This creates a function called `F1` which accepts a single parameter called `A`. Whatever argument is passed to `F1` will be set to `A`, so:

```
def F1(A):
  print A

F1('hello world')
```

In this code `F1` is called with the argument `'hello world'`. This argument is set to `A` and the function then runs `print A` which is now equivalent to `print 'hello world'`.

So in your function you're immediately reassigning `A` to `B`, but `B` hasn't been created anywhere in your code. The assignment `B=C` makes just as little sense.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Now I fix the logical sense of I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a shared object to store the results? Something like a `dict`:

```
def f1(data):
    data['b'] = data['a'] + 1

def f2(data):
    data['c'] = data['b'] + 1
    print data['c']

my_data = {'a': 1}

f1(my_data)
f2(my_data) # prints 3
```